# transfer, massage and import data with azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am working with Azure and have a number of sql databases on such.

I am looking to transfer data between databases on such. I have been doing some research and have found that azure data factory is a method that can be used to achieve. However, I found it difficult to find information on this.

Could someone point me in the direction of using data factory for taking data from db1, transform and massage it and then insert in to db2?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply COPY data from source A to source B, ADF is a good option for you. There is a rich set of supported sources and destinations.

To quickly try it out, you can use COPY wizard, which is code-free. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-copy-wizard

For more details about COPY activity, you may look at this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-data-movement-activities

When you said "massage data", I don't know what exactly it will be, but ADF [Custom Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities) and [Stored procedure Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-stored-proc-activity) should mostly meet your need.